# simple form not loading dynamicly created associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, simple-form

I got polymorphic has many through association

```
# a/m/documnet.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :possessions, as: :belonging
 has_many :clients, :through => :possessions, :source => :owner, :source_type => 'Client'
end
```

in console

```
Document.new.clients 
#=> []
```

in views with simple form

```
= f.association :clients, as: :check_boxes, collection: Client.all
```

it works without problem.

--

Issue starts when I want to dynamically associate has many resources

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :possessions, as: :belonging

  def self.possession_owner_classes
     [Client, SomethingElse]
  end
  possession_owner_classes.each do |possession_class|
    has_many possession_class.model_name.underscore.pluralize, :through => :possessions,  :source => :owner, :source_type => possession_class.model_name
  end
end
```

in console

```
Document.new.clients 
#=> []
```

in views with simple form

```
= f.association :clients, as: :check_boxes, collection: Client.all
```

will throw

```
Association :clients not found
```

so Rails know about this association but simple form doesn't  :-/   any ideas please ?

Comment: just reminder: please note that the association is working correctly, only when I'm dynamically creating it problems occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found the error,

```
has_many possession_class.model_name.underscore.pluralize, :through => :possessions,  :source => :owner, :source_type => possession_class.model_name
```

should be

```
has_many possession_class.model_name.underscore.pluralize.to_sym, :through => :possessions,  :source => :owner, :source_type => possession_class.model_name
```

so association name must be symbol not string

```
 :clients   # ok
 'clients'  # will blow up
```

huh :-\